# Failsafe Allocation

Tags: c, memory

I am working on windows XP. So I understand that auto variables are stored on the stack and the dynamically generated data of the pointer variables are stored on the heap.

Is the amount of stack memory and heap memory available to each program fixed. Can it be set different for a particular program? If yes then -> Is the setting done automatically by the system or does it have to be done manually in some way?

I am planning to create a huge array(say 50000 records) of a structure in C. I can only think of declaring it as one of the following:

1. global and statically created eg. struct Product products[50000];
2. local and dynamically created eg. struct Product *products; products = malloc(sizeof(struct Product)*50000);

I just know that:

- Calling too many functions(recursive or plain one in another) can use up the stack memory available.
- Malloc can fail meaning enough heap memory was not available.

Am I right?

The scenario is that the application would be open along with many others on the system. I do not want this application to crash because of lack of memory. So what would be the failsafe way to **have a huge array and eat it too**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic allocation takes (virtual) RAM from the operating system as needed.

You can control the maximum stack size by the /F compiler switch.

Comment: From what you say I get that if I were to draw a SET diagram then stack memory would be inside the process' memory(which in turn is a subset of the system memory). What about the heap memory? Does it come inside or outside of the process' memory area?

Comment: Each malloc (or other dynamic allocation) try to find a block inside the available heap and if there is none, it asks the operating system for more memory.
This block becomes a part of your process memory.

Answer (score 2):

50000 structures is not *that* big. You will not have any problems allocating them.
For this task use the dynamic allocation:

```
struct Product *products = malloc(sizeof(struct Product)*50000);
```

This way it will be easier for you to access your data as you have a pointer to it so you can pass it whenever you want. Moreover `malloc`returns NULL when an allocation fails so you handle allocation errors.

Although your RAM is limited, you do not use any memory to make a dynamic allocation.
For the static declaration, it is supposed not to fail usually but yet again your computer has some physical limits.
But you are not going to reach them.

Comment: Assume a larger array. What happens when the limits are reached? Will the program crash? Does virtual memory do anything at all to help here?

Comment: Malloc will return a null pointer, auto allocation will generate a Stack overflow (not to be confused with this web site).