# Not enough space for Global Data in C

Tags: c, global-variables

This is my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931859/failsafe-allocation) question
Here is part of my C code:

```
#define PROD_NAME_MAX 256
struct Product
{
    char name[PROD_NAME_MAX];
    long int quantity;
    long int category_id;
    char deleted;
};
#define PROD_MAX 1000000
struct Product products[PROD_MAX];
struct Product *pProducts[PROD_MAX];
```

I am working on Windows XP and PellesC. I undestand that there is not enough space for the global data in my C program. In the task manager I can see that "Mem Usage" increase to `268344k` and the process crashes. If `PROD_MAX` is `100000` then too there is a crash at another lesser value for "Mem Usage". If `PROD_MAX` is lesser, say `50000`, then there is no crash. My system has `1GB RAM`. What do I do? Is there a simple easy solution?

Comment: Windows XP (32 bit) only have 3GB virtual address space for applications.

Comment: Any reason you are using statically allocated arrays versus dynamic (heap)allocation?

Comment: YePhlcK:: I am using statically allocated array just like that for simplicity.

Comment: I wonder if the crash is for some other reason than the amount of data.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg:: What do you think then the maximum size of the array be?

Comment: The data you show takes about `(268+4)*1000000=272000000=259.4MB`. You have more than enough memory to deal with this, especially considering virtual memory.

Comment: Is C++ an option for you? C++ strings may be a lot more memory efficient than using 256 bytes for each of your product names.

Comment: @Étienne Or simply malloc the string data and store a pointer in the struct.

Comment: Can you use a debugger and check at which line your program is crashing? This may have nothing to do with RAM.

Comment: @ooga: or simply malloc (and, at times, realloc) the array of structs to keep its size to a minimum. I would either realloc (when the array is getting full) in fixed chunks, or double the size each time, depending on the needs.

Answer (score 2):

A general rule is to avoid consuming a huge lot of resources unless you are sure to need all of them.

<sup>It is the same in your real life: you won't buy several kilotons of bananas if you are not sure to eat all of them.</sup>

So you should, for example, `malloc` every individual `struct Product`. Then the number of products you would be able to handle would depend on the amount of (virtual) memory your operating system is able to give you.

Don't forget to test failure of `malloc` at least with some fatal error message:

```
struct Product *newprod = malloc(sizeof Product);
if (!newprod) { 
   perror("not enough memory for a Product"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then always initialize immediately every field of `newprod`. In principle you should get the habit of `free`-ing every such memory zone before end of program.

If you feel that your particular computer does not have enough resources for your real problem (the real world problem you are computing for), you'll need to get more resources, this becomes a social (e.g. asking your manager to buy a bigger computer) or an economic problem (spending a lot of money to buy a huge server), or a symptom of bad programming (then the needed resource is development time).

Of course what "lot of resources" means is subjective and have varied in the past: when I was a teenager (1970s) a megabyte of RAM was a huge amount. Today a gigabyte of RAM does not cost much. But you probably cannot afford a terabyte of RAM today. (Perhaps when you will retire, you might have terabytes of RAM at home).

Some famous scientist (Dijkstra maybe) said something like: "Computer Science is the mathematics of resources"

Perhaps having the `name` field be some [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)-ed field. You should guess if that is worth the effort (what do *you think* is the "average" name length? I have no idea) and adapt your code accordingly.

Likewise, the big array of pointers `pProducts`  could itself be dynamically heap-allocated (and you would e.g. use [realloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) or `malloc` for that pointer array). You could initially allocate it for 100 pointers, and e.g. increase it by half (`newsize = 3*oldsize/2;`) when it is getting full.

Reading wikipages about [C memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management), [fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29), [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), [memory pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool), [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (and googling on "memory overcommit") might be interesting to you.

Comment: I would not malloc every Product. I would malloc an array for it, and only realloc that array (by a large chunk) when it is full. Requires a little bookkeeping, but keeps memory from being fragmented and is far more performant.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I agree with you, but the OP is probably some kid learning how to program. Let him discover fragmentation later.

Comment: Sure, but if you malloc each Product individually, you'll need a place to store the pointers to them anyway, with the same problematics, unless you want to teach him about linked lists. <g>

Comment: I would write a simple program demonstrating what I mean, if I had a little more time. I have a few examples, but they are in Delphi, so no use here.

Comment: This discussion misses the point that it's probably not a memory problem at all.

Comment: I don't know. I *never* coded on Windows. And we don't know the entire source code.